# Can I search for strings within a function in python?

Tags: python

I have a main python function that runs ~50 smaller functions that each put key-value pair(s) into a main dict.
Sometimes these smaller functions fail (which is fine) but then they don't put their key-value pair(s) into the main dict. This causes an issue when I need all the keys later, even the failed ones.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
mainDict = {}

def littleFunction1(a,b):
    z = a+b
    mainDict['z'] = z

def main(a,b):
    try:
        littleFunction1(a,b)
    except:
        putKeysIntoMainDict(littleFunction1) # This function I cannot work out
    print(mainDict.keys()) # should print z
```

If the user runs main(2,4) that works, but if they run main('foo','bar') then littleFunction1 will error and z isn't entered into mainDict and the print will be blank.

Ideally putKeysIntoMainDict() searches through littleFunction1 to find mainDict['z'] = x and can return 'z'.

Everything I've found searching for 'search within a function' has just returned the search function for strings.

If there are alternative ways of doing the same thing I'd be happy with that too.

edit: Changed code to be (hopefully) clearer. It's an example, not my actual code because the littleFunctions I'm using are all 100s of lines long

Comment: What does it mean to "search through a function"?

Comment: To go through each line of the function as if it were a string and look for a particular string, in this case "mainDict['__']" and then return whats between the brackets

Comment: This is really an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you are trying to do doesn't make much sense. It would be much better if you describe in more detail the context and what you're trying to do so we can offer reasonable alternate ways of doing that

Comment: I think the first paragraph describes what I'm trying to do - I would like all the keys in the mainDict whether their respective functions run successfully or not. Ideally without having a static dict/list somewhere of all of the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this. Simply set a default value with each function. If it fails, you will still have that value set:

```py
def littleFunction1():
    mainDict['z'] = '-'
    x = 3
    y = 2
    z = x + y
    mainDict['z'] = z
```

Or even simpler, when accessing this `mainDict`, use [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). Any value that wasn't set in one of the functions will return a default value:

```py
>>> d = {'a': 5}
>>> d.get('a', '-')
5
>>> d.get('z', '-')
'-'
```

Comment: In the first one, if littleFunction1 errors then it won't set the first value either, though I could wrap the whole rest of it in a try block I suppose.

I'm trying to avoid stating 'z' at any point because it means every time I update a function I'll also have to update some list of all the keys I'm expecting, which creates a simple source of human error

Comment: Why not? It's literally the first line of the function. There is nothing there to fail...

Comment: So your question is not really clear. Try to edit the question with a [mre]

Comment: I've updated the main question to hopefully be clearer, so in this case even if I put mainDict['z'] = '-' at the top of littleFunction1 it will error when someone attempts main('foo','bar') and we end up in the except: part

Comment: I don't understand why it will fail. Do you know that if some error occurs at a function, only the following lines are not executed? Everything that happend before the error is valid. Therefore, if `mainDict['z'] = '-'` is the first line of the function it will always happen. Please try that code

Comment: So it can run half of the function within the try block, then fail and run the whole except block? I did not know this, thank you. I thought the point of a try was to not run code if it broke somewhere

Comment: But how can the program know that it is ***going to*** fail? Everything is run normally ***until*** an error occurs